# Docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity

Tags: docker-compose, archlinux

So I am trying to run searxng in a docker container, but it just loads a blank page. Running `docker-compose logs -f searxng` spits out the following:

```
searxng  | Traceback (most recent call last):
searxng  |   File "/usr/local/searxng/searx/search/processors/abstract.py", line 75, in initialize
searxng  |     self.engine.init(get_engine_from_settings(self.engine_name))
searxng  |   File "/usr/local/searxng/searx/engines/zlibrary.py", line 39, in init
searxng  |     resp = http_get('https://z-lib.org', timeout=5.0)
searxng  |   File "/usr/local/searxng/searx/network/__init__.py", line 165, in get
searxng  |     return request('get', url, **kwargs)
searxng  |   File "/usr/local/searxng/searx/network/__init__.py", line 96, in request
searxng  |     return future.result(timeout)
searxng  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 446, in result
searxng  |     return self.__get_result()
searxng  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
searxng  |     raise self._exception
searxng  |   File "/usr/local/searxng/searx/network/network.py", line 291, in request
searxng  |     return await self.call_client(False, method, url, **kwargs)
searxng  |   File "/usr/local/searxng/searx/network/network.py", line 287, in call_client
searxng  |     raise e
searxng  |   File "/usr/local/searxng/searx/network/network.py", line 272, in call_client
searxng  |     response = await client.request(method, url, **kwargs)
searxng  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1513, in request
searxng  |     return await self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
searxng  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1600, in send
searxng  |     response = await self._send_handling_auth(
searxng  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1628, in _send_handling_auth
searxng  |     response = await self._send_handling_redirects(
searxng  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1665, in _send_handling_redirects
searxng  |     response = await self._send_single_request(request)
searxng  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1702, in _send_single_request
searxng  |     response = await transport.handle_async_request(request)
searxng  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 307, in handle_async_request
searxng  |     with map_httpcore_exceptions():
searxng  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
searxng  |     self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
searxng  |   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 77, in map_httpcore_exceptions
searxng  |     raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
searxng  | httpx.ConnectTimeout
```

I'm running this on arch linux, maybe that could have something to do with it. Here is also my neofetch output:

```
- OS: Arch Linux x86_64
- Host: 81YM IdeaPad 5 14ARE05
- Kernel: 5.15.82-1-lts
- Packages: 1426 (pacman), 32 (flatpak)
- Shell: bash 5.1.16
- DE: GNOME 43.2
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4600U with Radeon Graphics (12) @ 2.100GHz
- GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Renoir
- Memory: 8790MiB / 15364MiB
```

- I followed all the steps for the installation, as well as following the 'How to use it' [Link](https://github.com/searxng/searxng-docker) with no errors.
- Running the command docker-compose up -d starts the containers without error, but trying to access `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `127.0.0.1:8080:8080` (as it states in the *docker-compose.yaml* file)